# Is it possible to combine 2 LINQ queries, each filtering data, before fetching the results of the queries?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to retrieve data from 2 SQL tables, using LINQ. I was hoping to combine them using a Join. I've looked this problem up on Stack Overflow, but all the questions and answers I've seen involve retrieving the data using ToList(), but I need to use lazy loading. The reason for this is there's too much data to fetch it all. Therefore, I've got to apply a filter to both queries before performing a ToList().

One of these queries is easily specified:

```cs
var solutions = ctx.Solutions.Where(s => s.SolutionNumber.Substring(0, 2) == yearsToConsider.PreviousYear || s.SolutionNumber.Substring(0, 2) == yearsToConsider.CurrentYear);
```

It retrieves all the data from the `Solution` table, where the `SolutionNumber` starts with either the current or previous year. It returns an IQueryable.

The thing that's tough for me to figure out is how to retrieve a filtered list from another table named `Proficiency`. At this point all I've got is this:

```cs
var profs = ctx.Proficiencies;
```

The `Proficiency` table has a column named SolutionID, which is a foreign key to the ID column in the `Solution` table. If I were doing this in SQL, I'd do a subquery where SolutionID is in a collection of IDs from the Solution table, where those Solution records match the same Where clause I'm using to retrieve the IQueryable for Solutions above. Only when I've specified both IQueryables do I want to then perform a ToList().

But I don't know how to specify the second LINQ query for Proficiency. How do I go about doing what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Instead write the logic in a stored procedure and call directly, then use Linq to manipulate the data for display/usage purposes as post processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you are trying to fetch ***Proficiencies*** based on some ***Solutions***. This might be achieved in two different ways. I'll try to provide solutions in Linq as it is more readable. However, you can change them in Lambda Expressions later.

**Solution 1**

```
var solutions = ctx.Solutions
               .Where(s => s.SolutionNumber.Substring(0, 2) == yearsToConsider.PreviousYear || s.SolutionNumber.Substring(0, 2) == yearsToConsider.CurrentYear)
               .Select(q => q.SolutionId);

var profs = (from prof in ctx.Proficiencies where (from sol in solutions select sol).Contains(prof.SolutionID) select prof).ToList();
```

or
**Solution 2**

```
   var profs = (from prof in ctx.Proficiencies 
                 join sol in ctx.Solutions on prof.SolutionId equals sol.Id 
                 where sol.SolutionNumber.Substring(0, 2) == yearsToConsider.PreviousYear || sol.SolutionNumber.Substring(0, 2) == yearsToConsider.CurrentYear
                 select prof).Distinct().ToList();
```

You can trace both queries in **SQL Profiler** to investigate the generated queries. But I'd go for the first solution as it will generate a subquery that is faster and does not use **Distinct** function that is not recommended unless you have to.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!